# Amazon Polly schedules the task instead of completing it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-polly

I am making a request to AWS polly to convert text to mp3 and when i make the call and check the status, it always gets scheduled and doesn't get completed.I am trying to store the generated mp3 file to S3 bucket but as the task does not get completed, i cannot see any file getting generated in S3 bucket.

Here i am creating the polly client object :

````
     ```private AmazonPollyAsync buildClient() {
        AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(awsConfig.accessKey(), awsConfig.secretKey()));
        AmazonPollyAsyncClientBuilder builder = AmazonPollyAsyncClientBuilder.standard();
        builder.setCredentials(credentialsProvider);
        builder.setRegion(awsConfig.awsRegion());
        return builder.build();
    }```
````

Here i am making the task request using polly object i have created :

````
         ```StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest synthesisTaskRequest = new 
                                                         StartSpeechSynthesisTaskRequest();
            synthesisTaskRequest.setVoiceId(voice.toString());
            synthesisTaskRequest.setOutputS3BucketName(awsConfig.s3Bucket());
            synthesisTaskRequest.setText(text);
            synthesisTaskRequest.setOutputFormat("mp3");
            StartSpeechSynthesisTaskResult result = 
            polly.startSpeechSynthesisTask(synthesisTaskRequest);```
````

Comment: What's the output of the startSpeechSynthesisTask() call?

Comment: @JulienSimon On evaluating the expression in IDE i was getting  `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError` but later on i found the solution. Problem was the region i was providing in the credentials as i didn't had the access to that region so S3 bucket didn't let the file store  and it was getting scheduled instead of getting completed

Comment: Good to hear you fixed it! If your question is not going to assist future readers, you are welcome to delete it.